# Get ID In Bulk inserting

Tags: sql-server, scope-identity

I am inserting SQL table data through XML file

```
<root>
  <Attributedata>
    <AttributeLabelID>-1</AttributeLabelID>
    <ProductID>1</ProductID>
    <AttributeLabel>User Label</AttributeLabel>
    <AttributeTypeID>1</AttributeTypeID>
    <Value>
        <valueID>-1 </valueID>
        <Uservalue>sss </Uservalue>
        <ProductAttributelID>1</ProductAttributelID>
    </Value>
    <Value>
        <valueID>-1 </valueID>
        <Uservalue>sss </Uservalue>
        <ProductAttributelID>1</ProductAttributelID>
    </Value>
    <CreatedBy >1</CreatedBy>
</Attributedata>
<Attributedata>

    <AttributeLabelID>-1</AttributeLabelID>
    <ProductID>1</ProductID>
    <AttributeLabel>User Label</AttributeLabel>
    <AttributeTypeID>1</AttributeTypeID>
    <Value>
        <valueID>-1 </valueID>
        <Uservalue>sss </Uservalue>
        <ProductAttributelID>1</ProductAttributelID>
    </Value>

    <CreatedBy >1</CreatedBy>
</Attributedata>
<Attributedata>

    <AttributeLabelID>-1</AttributeLabelID>
    <ProductID>1</ProductID>
    <AttributeLabel>User Label</AttributeLabel>
    <AttributeTypeID>1</AttributeTypeID>
    <Value>
        <valueID>-1 </valueID>
        <Uservalue>sss </Uservalue>
        <ProductAttributelID>1</ProductAttributelID>
    </Value>
    <Value>
        <valueID>-1 </valueID>
        <Uservalue>sss </Uservalue>
        <ProductAttributelID>1</ProductAttributelID>
    </Value>
    <CreatedBy >1</CreatedBy>
</Attributedata>
</root>
```

In table 1, `Attributevalueid` is auto generated and primary key. I want to insert at that time `Attributevalueid` in another table table2 - how it is possible through a stored procedure?

Comment: those knighted are probably not programmers, and you'd want to present better English to those knighted. (Y).

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a trigger.

Please, retag your questions.

Comment: but i have inserted more data in details table

Answer (score 1):

Use the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( AttributeValueId int )

INSERT TABLE_NAME ( ... )
SELECT ...
FROM ....
OUTPUT 
    Inserted.AttributeValueId INTO @t

INSERT OTHER_TABLE ( ... )
SELECT AttributeValueId
FROM @t
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the trigger response, but you could also change the field from Identity to a regular int and use a counter table.  It would require some additional logic on your end but not a lot and you could keep all of your business logic within your app.

I would still go with the trigger suggestion.  I'm only offering this as an alternative that has worked well for me in other situations.